# Problemas con imagenes reactjs y webpack

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, webpack

estoy aprendiendo reactjs y quiero saber como renderisar una imagen con webpack y react [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es mi loader y aqui trato de renderisar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas David, acostumbrate a poner el código en el post y no en fotos para que podamos copiar-lo y poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: gracias lo tomare en cuenta para la proxima es mi primer preguntar lo siento

Comment: @DavidArellano para la proxima no es necesario, puedes [edit] para mejorar esta ya. Que sea la primera pregunta no significa que no tenga que tener cierta calidad. Por favor haz lo que Marc te indica de las images y mira [ask] para mejorar esta y futuras pregunas. Un saludo

Answer (score -2):

problema resuelto solo estaba ocupando el loader equivocado tengo que usar url-loader en lugar de file-loader igual si tienen manuales de buenas practicas sobre node y react seran vienvenidos

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código completo con el que resolviste? Para que sea más útil la respuesta para futuros lectores :)